# Is a TCAS capable of handling three (or more) planes on "crash course"?

Tags: tcas

I asked myself if the TCAS is capable to handle, the very unlikely situation, that three (or more) planes are simultaneously on "crash course" (Sorry, got no other word for it).

If not, how would the TCAS "react"?

Thanks.